# In XSD I want to specify that an element can only have whitespace content

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

The following XSD should allow for an element called OnlyWhiteSpaceElement which has a required Name attribute, and can have only whitespace content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:complexType name="OnlyWhiteSpaceType">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="OnlyWhiteSpaceContentType">
                <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:simpleType name="OnlyWhiteSpaceContentType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:whiteSpace value="collapse"/>
            <xs:length value="0"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:complexType name="MyType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="OnlyWhiteSpaceElement" type="OnlyWhiteSpaceType"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="MyXml" type="MyType">
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The XSD is in a file called Temp.XSD, and here is the XML that is validated by it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MyXml xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Temp.xsd">
    <OnlyWhiteSpaceElement Name="MyOnlyWhiteSpaceElement">

    </OnlyWhiteSpaceElement>
</MyXml>
```

However the validation fails. The end tag  shows an error that reads

```
The 'OnlyWhiteSpaceElement' element is invalid - the value '     ' is invalid according to its datatype 'OnlyWhiteSpaceType' - the actual length is not equal to the specified length.
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be some differences in how XSD validating parser implementations interpret:

```
<xs:whiteSpace value="collapse"/>
```

Xerces will prune away leading and trailing whitespace remaining after collapsing internal whitespace, but the XSD validators in [.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/666192/290085) and [Liquid XML Studio](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/xmlschema-dev/2009Mar/0017.html) apparently do not collapse such cases to the empty string.

It's probably better to avoid the issue altogether and use `xs:pattern` instead:

```
  <xs:pattern value="\s*"/>
```

Here's the entire XSD updated with the above change:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:complexType name="OnlyWhiteSpaceType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="OnlyWhiteSpaceContentType">
        <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:simpleType name="OnlyWhiteSpaceContentType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="\s*"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:complexType name="MyType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="OnlyWhiteSpaceElement" type="OnlyWhiteSpaceType"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:element name="MyXml" type="MyType">
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```